# Replace a texture by another

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, texture, blending, blend-modes

With Photoshop, how is it possible to keep the structure of this woodworking:

[image]

but replace the wood texture by another, like this one:

[image]

?

I can imagine it's possible with two layers, and a special "blending mode" for each one, I have tried a few, but haven't found the good one(s).

(The "woodworking structure" is probably defined by the dark lines / contours)

Comment: In Photoshop, with the source material as it is, it is not possible.

Comment: Have you considered a solution using 3D rendering? You mention in another comment that you have many of these to generate. Going 3D might be a more viable option in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it black & white

[image: Make it black and white]

Light it up

[image: Light it up]

Brush a bit over it so its smooth

[image: Brush over the texture]

Multiply over new texture

[image: Multiply over new texture]

Setup

[image: Setup]

Comment: Very nice, it's exactly what I was looking for! The layer `Image` is on Multiply, and `New Texture` on Normal, or the contrary?

Comment: @Basj depends on the stacking order. Top layer should have multiply so whatever is below it shines through. With this order, it would be the Image layer. Since all layers above Image are in a Clipping mask with image, they inherit it.

Comment: Very cool solution, thanks again. Last detail: what tool do you usually use to "Brush a bit over it so its smooth" (there are many solutions, but I wondered which ones are the faster)?

Comment: @Basj, this answer does get the job done and quickly, but it is quite specific to this panel. Like if you compare the original to the new one, you can still see the texture of the old frame on the sides. The "brush a bit over it so it's smooth" is relying on that same thing.  You don't have to make it perfect. If there is some bleed through it may even look a bit more natural than if like the edge is totally sharp. I'm not the OP, but it looks to me he used the brush tool with soft round brush, as in a circle brush with 0 hardness. Sorta like you would use spray paint in real life.

Comment: This is basically the same answer as given by @BillyKerr: Use a white painted panel. But here only the inner part of the panel has been turned into a white painted panel. The rest is left unchanged and shows traces of the old texture. The real trouble starts if you want to paint the entire panel white. Then it's basically manual painting/drawing.

Comment: @Basj The Layer "New Texture" is all at the bottom so it's displayed as normal always. (as it has nothing blow to combine itself)

Comment: I don't quiet remember I think I used the stamp tool with low opacity & hardness. As it is very geometric one also can use polygon &rectangular select to affect only the flat areas.
It also can be really handy to use a gaussian blur on a smart object so one can blur certain parts with a smart filter mask.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say it's probably a waste of time and not worth the effort. The top image is such poor quality that it's unusable anyway.

Instead, just find a white painted wood panel (or take a photo of one), paste it as a new layer on top of your texture layer, and set the layer blending mode to multiply.

Example

[image]

Comment: In fact I have many different woodworkings, not only this generic one, so I'm looking for a solution that works as described in the question. Thanks for your answer anyway!  About `The top image is such poor quality that it's unusable anyway.` it was just an image among many, I have reduced the size here, but I have some in higher res.

Comment: @Basj - the problem is you'd somehow have to remove the wood texture off the panel first, that's why it's not worth the effort, even if the resolution is better.

Comment: For my application it *is* worth the effort, because I have a few different woodworkings to process. Some of them have a very precise moulding/millwork, for which I can't find an equivalent easily in white on internet. I was looking for a solution that doesn't require to remove the initial wood texture: I thought it could be possible with a processing that keeps the dark "lines" i.e. the contours of the moulding.

Comment: @Basj The problem is the texture in the panel is also made of dark lines - and separating these lines from those you want to keep is not a trivial task.  There is a way of course, but it would probably involve painting or smudging out the texture. There's nothing that is going to do it automatically for you - what I say "effort" I mean manual effort, and a considerable amount of time spent doing so.

Comment: I see @BillyKerr, thank you for your answer. I'm okay to spend this amount of time, I need to achieve this.

Comment: @Billy Kerr This is only a starting point because using only one layer with multiply will only render shadows and not highlights.

Comment: @Rafael, yes, a second wood panel layer with a different blend mode for highlights would certainly improve it - "Overlay" would probably work. However the OP doesn't want to go down this route anyway.

Comment: I think what @BillyKerr means is that there isn't really a method or trick. You need to do so much manual painting that you are actually drawing the structure from scratch. That's _my_ opinion anyway.

Comment: @Wolff - that's precisely what I meant.  I notice the answer chosen as best by the OP is  for a rather poor quality attempt at reconstruction of the panel, so I guess he/she doesn't care too much anyway about the quality.

Answer (score 2):

There is no algorithm right now that I know that can do what you need using that image.

Even if it was a 3D model using the same wood texture, the shadows are now combined with the wood texture so basically, the information is mixed and lost.

I took a quick look separating channels but the info is sooo contaminated it is useless.

[image]

I agree with Bill Ker, but let's explore some things.

If you have the wood carvings on some physical samples try to **paint them in white** so you can extract the carving itself using proper illumination.

Use a glossy paint so you can extract also the highlights.

---

But the best way to do that is either using a real 3D program and make your own carvings in 3D or preparing a Photoshop Mockup with different layers.

Here is a possible cross-section to be used as a 3D model later.

[image]